# Google Spreadsheet: How to count two arrays common datas?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have 2 arrays:

A[1,2,3]

B[3,4,5]

How do I count the piece of common datas in Google Spreadsheet? The expected result is 1 (because 3 is the common data in the two arrays).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
=COUNTIF(ArrayFormula(match(A:A,B:B,0)), ">0")
```

Changes ranges to suit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but it works...

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,("\[|\]"),""),","),MATCH(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,("\[|\]"),""),","),SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B1,("\[|\]"),""),","),0))))
```